# How can I link these two objects (imagemap shape and checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an imagemap collection of shapes and a bunch of checkboxes, how can I make it so when a shape is clicked the corresponding checkbox is selected and vice versa?

Imagemap:

```
<div class="map_container">

  <%= image_tag("maps/mainmap.png", :width => "450", :height => "450", :class => "map", :usemap => "#mainmap", :alt => "") %>

  <map name="mainmap">
    <area id="north" shape="poly" 
      coords="158,43,152,49,164,86,165,112,153,153,139,169,145,171,161,176,236,201,241,202,251,166,253,142,257,132,294,102,269,85,240,68,227,53,213,28,202,27" alt="North"
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >

    <area id="south" shape="poly" 
      coords="38,288,16,361,13,374,18,380,69,403,183,408,217,390,199,352,188,330,177,321,169,317,40,284" alt=""
      data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"5F9EA0","fillOpacity":0.6}'
      onmouseover="document.body.style.cursor='pointer'" 
      onmouseout="document.body.style.cursor='default'" >
  </map>              
</div>
```

Checkboxes:

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <%= form_tag '', :method => :get, :id => 'filter_form' do %>

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
        <p class="area_check"><%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
        <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label></p>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="filter_form_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This gives this output:

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" id="filter_form" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>        

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">

        <p class="area_check"><input id="area-41" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="41" />
        <label for="area-41"><p1>North</p1></label></p>
        <p class="area_check"><input id="area-42" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="42" />
        <label for="area-42"><p1>South</p1></label></p>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="filter_form_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
</form></div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to provide some kind of "link" between the `<area>`s and the checkboxes. Some property which matches pairs together. Right now your `<area>`s have alt tags of "north" and "south" but the checkboxes have the seemingly unrelated ids of 41 and 42. How about match them up so you don't have to do a bunch of traversal, eg:

```
$('area').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('alt');
    var $checkbox = $('[name=' + name + ']');
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

would go well with html like:

```
North<input name="north" type="checkbox" />

South<input name="south" type="checkbox" />

...

  <area shape="rect" coords="137,17,285,120" href="#" alt="north">
  <area shape="rect" coords="152,165,292,327" href="#" alt="south">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daTEg/16/)

**edit:** the key is just matching `<area>`s to `<input>`s, ideally you can craft your html so that matching pairs have something in common, but if worst comes to worst you have 2 fallback methods.

**1) Order:** if the `<area>`s are in the same order as the checkboxes, and they each have a partner you could rely on that correspondence:

```
$('area').click(function(i){
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    var $checkbox = $('.areas input[type="checkbox"]').eq(i);
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

this will use the index "i" of the  you clicked to pick the checkbox of the same index.

**2) A direct mapping that you write into your javascript:**

```
var CBids = {
    "north" : "area-41"
    "south" : "area-41"
};

$('area').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    var $checkbox = $('#' + CBids[name] );
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and fiddle thats exactly what I was after. Is there a way of linking without changing the checkbox id's? Only the checkboxes are created from a database and I'm not sure how I can change the id from its key field. Thanks again though much appreciated!

Comment: sure, I've added a couple methods to match them up with each other, but these are by no means all of the ways you could match areas to checkboxes